# Можно ли разархивировать полученный по сети файла не сохраняя его на диск?

Tags: node.js, zip

Мобильный разработчик собирается присылать мне заархивированные json файлы.

Самый примитивный алгоритм извлечения полезных данных - зааплоадить файл (сохранить на диск), прочитать его и распаковать (результат сохранить на диск), прочитать распакованный файл (т.к. это .json можно результат операции require сразу сохранять в переменную), удалить .json, удалить .zip.
Что-то много лишних телодвижений.

Получающийся при распаковке readStream я уже сообразил как превратить в объект, не сохраняя промежуточный файл на диск.

Есть ли способ сразу передать в "разархиватор" (пока использую yauzl) поток для преобразования, не сохраняя файл на диск?
Для аплоада использую busboy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например можете файл записать в буфер и из буфера декомпрессовать. 
Вот модуль который умеет подобное [adm-zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip)

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov ну это свинство! Если вы считаете, что метод fromBuffer из пакета yauzl будет использовать оптимальней (соглашусь, для меня это даже удобней), чем использовать предложенный Романом пакет adm-zip - так дайте свой альтернативный ответ на вопрос! Вы же не  просто исправили грамматическую или речевую ошибку в ответе Романа, а полностью подменили его! И в Вашем ответе предлагается схожее, но все же другое решение, чем предложил Роман. Что же получается, человек не имеет права озвучить своего мнения по решению проблемы, если оно Вам кажется неоптимальным? Очень некрасиво!

Comment: @Roman нет необходимости менять используемую библиотеку, поскольку у yauzl есть функция [fromBuffer](https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl#frombufferbuffer-options-callback)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88621/discussion-on-answer-by-roman-polshikov------).